# Does auto make C++ code harder to understand?

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw a conference by Herb Sutter where he encourages every C++ programmer to use `auto`.

I had to read C# code some time ago where `var` was extensively used and the code was very hard to understand—every time `var` was used I had to check the return type of the right side. Sometimes more than once, because I forgot the type of the variable after a while!

I know the compiler knows the type and I don’t have to write it, but it is widely accepted that we should write code for programmers, not for compilers.

I also know that is more easy to write:

```
auto x = GetX();
```

Than:

```
someWeirdTemplate<someOtherVeryLongNameType, ...>::someOtherLongType x = GetX();
```

But this is written only once and the `GetX()` return type is checked many times to understand what type `x` has.

This made me wonder—does `auto` make C++ code harder to understand?

Comment: Checking the type of `x` does not seem to be easier than checking the return type of `GetX`, does it?

Comment: @KirilKirov But it is when GetX() is in another file and you have to jump from one file to another.

Comment: Do you really need to check the return type *every time*? Why isn't the type clear from the code? `auto` can often makes things harder to read when they are already hard to read, i.e., functions too long, variables poorly named, etc. On short functions with decently named variables, knowing the types should be one of #1 easy or #2 irrelevant.

Comment: @Felics - most of the good editors, have keyboard shortcuts for "jump to declaration/definition". And shortcuts for "back". That would mean, that you can check the return type within 2 fast steps. Also, most good editors show the javadoc + the function declaration, when you move the mouse pointer over the function, you need to call.

Comment: The "art" of using `auto` is a lot like determining when to use `typedef`. It's up to you to determine when it hinders and when it helps.

Comment: I thought I had the same problem, but then I realized that I can just understand the code without knowing the types. e.g.: "auto idx = get_index();" so idx is something holding an index. What the exact type is, is quite irrelevant for most cases.

Comment: So don't write `auto x = GetX();`, pick a better name than `x` that actually tells you what it does _in that specific context_  ... that's often more useful than its type anyway.

Comment: With all of the other ridiculous crap that's in the C++ language, I highly doubt that type inference can make it any more unreadable! ;)

Comment: I don't do a lot of programming in C++, but I've never found type inference to be a hindrance in other languages. Haskell and Scala both use it extensively. I also find myself using var regularly in C#, especially in cases like "var dict = new Dictionary<...>()".

Comment: If using more type inference makes it hard for a programmer to read the code, either the code or the programmer needs serious improvement.

Comment: Just use `typedef`-shortcuts when types are crucial for understanding code and `auto`, when they're obvious.

Comment: Many programmers will find type information useless altogether. And limiting it to some degree would not harm even if you're into static typing.

Comment: "I had to check the return type of the right side" -- There's no need to know the types of things, just what they represent, which is best done through good names.

Comment: Besides code readability and other considerations, to me 'auto' also takes away the ease of code browsing in IDEs like Visual Studio or SlickEdit. When the type is explicitly listed, I can get to the type definition with few clicks/keystrokes.

Comment: Just encode the type into the name of `x` using [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). 

Comment: Using 'auto' breaks the autocomplete/intellisense in Visual Studio. Still. In 2020.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Short answer: More completely, my current opinion on `auto` is that you should use `auto` by default unless you explicitly want a conversion. (Slightly more precisely, "... unless you want to explicitly commit to a type, which nearly always is because you want a conversion.")

Longer answer and rationale:

Write an explicit type (rather than `auto`) only when you really want to explicitly commit to a type, which nearly always means you want to explicitly get a conversion to that type. Off the top of my head, I recall two main cases:

- (Common) The `initializer_list` surprise that `auto x = { 1 };` deduces `initializer_list`. If you don’t want `initializer_list`, say the type -- i.e., explicitly ask for a conversion.
- (Rare) The expression templates case, such as that `auto x = matrix1 * matrix 2 + matrix3;` captures a helper or proxy type not meant to be visible to the programmer. In many cases, it's fine and benign to capture that type, but sometimes if you really want it to collapse and do the computation then say the type -- i.e., again explicitly ask for a conversion.

Routinely use `auto` by default otherwise, because using `auto` avoids pitfalls and makes your code more correct, more maintainable and robust, and more efficient. Roughly in order from most to least important, in the spirit of "write for clarity and correctness first":

- **Correctness:** Using `auto` guarantees you’ll get the right type. As the saying goes, if you repeat yourself (say the type redundantly), you can and will lie (get it wrong). Here's a usual example: `void f( const vector<int>& v ) { for( /*…*` -- at this point, if you write the iterator’s type explicitly, you want to remember to write `const_iterator` (did you?), whereas `auto` just gets it right.
- **Maintainability and robustness:** Using `auto` makes your code more robust in the face of change, because when the expression's type changes, `auto` will continue to resolve to the correct type. If you instead commit to an explicit type, changing the expression's type will inject silent conversions when the new type converts to the old type, or needless build breaks when the new type still works-like the old type but doesn't convert to the old type (for example, when you change a `map` to an `unordered_map`, which is always fine if you aren't relying on order, using `auto` for your iterators you'll seamlessly switch from `map<>::iterator` to `unordered_map<>::iterator`, but using `map<>::iterator` everywhere explicitly means you'll be wasting your valuable time on a mechanical code fix ripple, unless an intern is walking by and you can foist off the boring work on them).
- **Performance:** Because `auto` guarantees no implicit conversion will happen, it guarantees better performance by default. If instead you say the type, and it requires a conversion, you will often silently get a conversion whether you expected it or not.
- **Usability:** Using `auto` is your only good option for hard-to-spell and unutterable types, such as lambdas and template helpers, short of resorting to repetitive `decltype` expressions or less-efficient indirections like `std::function`.
- **Convenience:** And, yes, `auto` is less typing. I mention that last for completeness because it's a common reason to like it, but it's not the biggest reason to use it.

Hence: Prefer to say `auto` by default. It offers so much simplicity and performance and clarity goodness that you're only hurting yourself (and your code's future maintainers) if you don't. Only commit to an explicit type when you really mean it, which nearly always means you want an explicit conversion.

Yes, there is (now) a [GotW](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) about this.

Comment: I find auto useful even when I do want a conversion. It allows me to explicitly ask for a conversion without repeating the type: `auto x = static_cast<X>(y)`. The `static_cast` makes it clear that the conversion is on purpose and it avoids compiler warnings about the conversion. Normally avoiding compiler warnings isn't so good, but I'm OK with not getting a warning about a conversion that I considered carefully when I wrote `static_cast`. Though I wouldn't do this if there are no warnings now but I want to get warnings in future if the types change in a potentially dangerous way.

Comment: One thing I find with `auto` is that we should strive to program against *interfaces* (not in the OOP sense), not against specific implementations. It's the same with templates, really. Do you complain about "hard to read code" because you have a template type parameter `T` that is used everywhere? No, I don't think so. In templates too we code against an interface, compile-time duck-typing is what many people call it.

Comment: _"Using auto guarantees you’ll get the right type."_ Not true at all. It only guarantees you'll get the type prescribed by some other part of your code. Whether that's right or not is entirely unclear when you hide it away behind `auto`.

Comment: I am really surprised that nobody cares about IDEs... Even modern IDEs do not correctly support jumping to class/struct definition in case of `auto` variable, but almost all of them do it correctly with explicit type specification. Nobody uses IDE? Everybody uses only int/float/bool variables? Everybody prefers external documentation for libraries instead of self-documented headers?

Comment: that GotW: https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/ I don't see how that "initializer_list surprise" is a surprise; braces around `=` RHS don't make much sense by any other interpretation (bar braced init-list, but you need to know what you're initialising, which is an oxymoron with `auto`). The one that **is** surprising is `auto i{1}` also deducing `initializer_list`, despite implying not  _take this braced init-list_ but rather _take this expression and use its type_... but we get `initializer_list` there too. Thankfully, C++17 fixes all this up well.

Comment: I disagree with this answer, and I’d be curious to know if you’ve changed your stance in the meantime (and might thus want to rewrite the answer). Your answer currently states that you wouldn’t use `auto` when you want to perform a conversion. Why is that? You’d be giving up syntactic uniformity. I prefer using `auto` *even in these situations* (despite the added verbosity), and perform explicit coercion (either via a cast or uniform initialisation). So in the situations above I’d write, respectively, (1) e.g. `auto x = int8_t{1};`, and (2) `auto x = matrix{matrix1 * matrix 2 + matrix3};`.

Comment: This answer lists reasons in favour of using 'auto', but it doesn't address Mircea's point on readability.

Comment: I think Herb probably moved on a long time ago, but I'll comment anyway. I like his work, but I have to disagree here. I like duck typed programming. I enjoy using Python and I actually have quite a big soft spot for Objective-C, and personally I think method calls and OOP are best in duck typed languages. I like how templates let me do duck typing. However, I personally I am on board for "auto when it makes sense", I think "almost always auto" is a shocking oversimplification. Search SO for auto mistakes and problems, there's plenty...

Comment: 1) "Using auto guarantees you’ll get the right type" no, it automatically matches the type at time of compiling the function and spreads that type throughout your code. You're not finding the right type, you're delegating that job to somebody else. You've now got a "type dependency", your code is now going to change along with that thing that you used auto on. If that's what you want, great, but I think you should make it clearer what you're signing up for with this. It has its own gotcha situations.

Comment: 2) "the new type still works-like the old type but doesn't convert to the old type", I can sympathize with the annoyance of having to edit old code when you or I know full well that it's really the same thing, I really can. In this case I think Duck Typing really shines! However I would say this is more of a bad OOP design problem, why isn't there a base class I can use that has the same iterator behavior? The answer is probably because the STL wasn't designed for it, which is fair, but not everyone is maintaining a 20 year old library.

Comment: "Implicit conversions" --  it's true that `auto` itself will not implicitly convert (which is great), but if you attempt to *do something* with the `auto` variable (like assign an `auto` `double` to an `int`), an implicit conversion may happen at that point anyway and it may be harder to find it.

Comment: 3) "Unutterable types": Yes, absolutely use auto for these. "Hard to spell types", `using` is IMO a much better option, not just for the sake of saving typing but also making self-documenting code, you can make a context or application specific `using` that informs the reader exactly what the type means, instead of sweeping it under the rug. If it's hard to type out, it's probably also hard for the reader to understand, so personally I'd appreciate a `using` over (or in addition to) `auto`.

Comment: And I guess to round it out, I like duck typing in ObjC and Python, because their duck typing systems were designed with that in mind. C isn't duck typed, e.g., you need to know whether something is an `int` because of signed overflow UB. There's other cases in the standard that call out explicit types. If a well formed C++ application must take into account explicit types to be compliant, AAA will make that harder. Any explicit type that's only well defined under certain conditions needs special handling; how should that be handled if `auto` takes the explicit type away?

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is asking about readability. If you see this comment please downvote this answer. I think the one by Joseph Mansfield should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 116):

It's a case-by-case situation.

It sometimes makes code harder to understand, sometimes not. Take, for instance:

```
void foo(const std::map<int, std::string>& x)
{
   for ( auto it = x.begin() ; it != x.end() ; it++ )
   { 
       //....
   }
}
```

is definitely easy to understand **and** definitely easier to write than the actual iterator declaration.

I've been using C++ for a while now, but I can guarantee that I'd get a compiler error at my first shot at this because I'd forget about the `const_iterator` and would initially go for the `iterator`... :)

I'd use it for cases like this, but not where it actually obfuscates the type (like your situation), but this is purely subjective.

Comment: Exactly. Who the heck cares about the type. It's an iterator. I don't care about the type, all I need to know is that I can use it to iterate.

Comment: +1. Even if you did name the type, you'd name it as `std::map<int, std::string>::const_iterator`, so it's not as if the name tells you much about the type anyway.

Comment: @SteveJessop: It tells me two things at least : the key is `int`, and the value is `std::string`. :)

Comment: @Nawaz: and that you can't assign to `it->second` since it's a const iterator. All of which information is a repeat of what's in the previous line, `const std::map<int, std::string>& x`. Saying things multiple times does occasionally inform better, but by no means is that a general rule :-)

Comment: Also note that having a properly named `x` would make knowing the type here even less interesting. At the end of the day, I think that responsible use of `auto` leads to much better names and thus more readable code.

Comment: TBH I'd prefer `for (anX : x)` to make it even more obvious we're just iterating over `x`. The normal case where you need an iterator is when you're modifying the container, but `x` is `const&`

Comment: I've only started writing iterator loops since `auto`.

Comment: The other interesting thing about that loop is that it works for any x with forward iterators.  It doesn't matter if x is an array, a list, a map, whatever.  If all you've decided at this point is that x will be a container containing a specific type of object, you can just write this and not come back to it.

Comment: imo the example should use cbegin() and cend() as it's (sort of) more const-correct and because it clarifies the intent better especially in the light of auto: it tells 'hey I'm a const iterator' and you don't even have to look at the definition of x to know it is.

Comment: then the next point is that the code would be made even more generic by using the non-member `std::cbegin|end()`, as those can work for plain arrays too, which is especially useful when writing templates, but could equally work if you changed the argument to a reference-to-array type. (then there's a more general argument to prefer non-members wherever possible, though I don't really grasp all the angles of that one)

Comment: @stijn no, it's totally fine to use `begin()` and `end()`. The intention is "give me this range", which is what you get. Now that we have `std::as_const` we don't need `cbegin` etc.

Answer (score 95):

Look at it another way. Do you write:

```
std::cout << (foo() + bar()) << "\n";
```

or:

```
// it is important to know the types of these values
int f = foo();
size_t b = bar();
size_t total = f + b;

std::cout << total << "\n";
```

Sometimes it doesn't help to spell the type out explicitly.

The decision whether you need to mention the type isn't the same as the decision whether you want to split the code across multiple statements by defining intermediate variables. In C++03 the two were linked, you can think of `auto` as a way to separate them.

Sometimes making the types explicit can be useful:

```
// seems legit    
if (foo() < bar()) { ... }
```

vs.

```
// ah, there's something tricky going on here, a mixed comparison
if ((unsigned int)foo() < bar()) { ... }
```

In cases where you declare a variable, using `auto` lets the type go unspoken just as it is in many expressions. You should probably try to decide for yourself when that helps readability and when it hinders.

You can argue that mixing signed and unsigned types is a mistake to begin with (indeed, some argue further that one should not use unsigned types at all). The *reason* it's arguably a mistake is that it makes the types of the operands vitally important because of the different behaviour. If it's a bad thing to need to know the types of your values, then it probably isn't also a bad thing not to need to know them. So provided the code isn't already confusing for other reasons, that makes `auto` OK, right? ;-)

Particularly when writing generic code there are cases where the actual type of a variable *shouldn't* be important, what matters is that it satisfies the required interface. So `auto` provides a level of abstraction where you ignore the type (but of course the compiler doesn't, it knows). Working at a suitable level of abstraction can help readability quite a lot, working at the "wrong" level makes reading the code a slog.

Comment: +1 `auto` allows you to create named variables with unnameable or uninteresting types. Meaningful names can be useful.

Comment: Mixing signed and unsigned if you use unsigned for the proper use: modular arithmetic. It isn't if you misuse unsigned for positive integer. Almost no program has a use for unsigned, but the core language forces its inane definition of `sizeof` as unsigned on you.

Answer (score 31):

There are several reasons why I dislike `auto` for the general use:

1. You can refactor code without modifying it. Yes, this is one of the things often listed as a benefit of using auto. Just change the return type of a function, and if all of the code that calls it uses auto, no additional effort is required! You hit compile, it builds - 0 warnings, 0 errors - and you just go ahead and check your code in without having to deal with the mess of looking through and potentially modifying the 80 places the function is used.

  But wait, is that really a good idea? What if the type mattered in a half dozen of those use-cases, and now that code actually behaves differently? This applied especially low level hardware program. This can also implicitly break "Encapsulation" by modifying not just the input values, but the behavior itself of the private implementation of other classes that call the function.

  1a.  I'm a believer in the concept of "Self-Documenting Code".  The reasoning behind self-documenting code is that comments tend to become out-of-date, no longer reflecting what the code is doing, whereas the code itself - if written in an explicit manner - is self-explanatory, always stays up to date on its intent, and won't leave you confused with stale comments. If types can be changed without needing to modify the code itself though, then the code/variables themselves can become stale.  For example:

`auto bThreadOK = CheckThreadHealth();`

Except the problem is that `CheckThreadHealth()` at some point was refactored to return an `enum` value indicating the error status, if any, instead of a bool. But the person who made that change missed inspecting this particular line of code, and the compiler was of no help because it compiled without warnings or errors.

2. You may never know what the actual types are. This is also often listed as a primary "Benefit" of `auto`. Why learn what a function is giving you, when you can just say, "It still compiles!"

  It even kind of works, probably. I say kind of works, because even though you're making a copy of a 500 byte struct for every loop iteration, so you can inspect a single value on it, the code is still completely functional.  So even your unit tests don't help you realize that bad code is hiding behind that simple and innocent-looking auto.  Most other people scanning through the file won't notice it on first glance either.

  This also can be made worse if you don't know what the type is, but you choose a variable name that makes a wrong assumption about what it is, in effect achieving the same result as in the list "1a", but from the very beginning rather than post-refactor.

3. Typing the code when initially writing it isn't the most time consuming part of programming. Yes, `auto` makes writing some code faster initially. As a disclaimer, I do type > 100 WPM, so maybe it doesn't bother me as much as others. But if all I had to do was write new code all day, I'd be a happy camper. The most time consuming part of programming is diagnosing hard-to-reproduce, edge-case bugs in the code, often which result from subtle non-obvious problems - such as the kind overuse of auto is likely to introduce (reference vs. copy, `signed` vs. `unsigned`, `float` vs. `int`, Boolean vs. Pointer, etc.).

  It seems obvious to me that auto was introduced primarily as a workaround for terrible syntax with standard library template types.  Rather than try to fix the template syntax that people are already familiar with - which may also be nearly impossible to do because of all of the existing code it could break - add in a keyword that basically hides the problem. Essentially what you might call a "hack".

I actually don't have any disagreement with the use of `auto` with Standard Library containers. It's obviously what the keyword was created for at C++11, and functions in the standard library are not likely to fundamentally change in purpose (or type for that matter), making 'auto' relatively safe to use. At the same time, some people feel that the "C++" doesn't like the "C++" anymore, [post of C++ Defeat The Purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69801126/doesnt-constraining-the-auto-in-c-defeat-the-purpose-of-it). I would be cautious about using it with your own code and interfaces that may be more volatile, and potentially subject to more fundamental changes.

Another useful application of `auto` that enhances the capability of the language is creating temporaries in type-agnostic macros. This is something you couldn't really do before, but you may do it now.

Comment: You nailed it. Wish I could give this a +2.

Comment: A good "be damned cautious"-answer. @cmaster: There it is.

Comment: I have found one more useful case: `auto something = std::make_shared<TypeWithLongName<SomeParam>>(a,b,c);`. :-)

Comment: I mostly suffer from #3 above. You try to read a code to find a bug and you see 10 lines with auto... No  any clue what types are beneath or what they do

Answer (score 27):

IMO, you're looking at this pretty much in reverse.

It's not a matter of `auto` leading to code that's unreadable or even less readable. It's a matter of (hoping that) having an explicit type for the return value will make up for the fact that it's (apparently) not clear what type would be returned by some particular function.

At least in my opinion, if you have a function whose return type isn't immediately obvious, that's your problem right there. What the function does should be obvious from its name, and the type of the return value should be obvious from what it does. If not, that's the real source of the problem.

If there's a problem here, it's not with `auto`. It's with the rest of the code, and chances are pretty good that the explicit type is just enough of a band-aid to keep you from seeing and/or fixing the core problem. Once you've fixed that real problem, readability of the code using `auto` will generally be just fine.

I suppose in fairness I should add: I've dealt with a few cases where such things weren't nearly as obvious as you'd like, and fixing the problem was fairly untenable as well. Just for one example, I did some consulting for a company a couple years ago that had previously merged with another company. They ended up with a code base that was more "shoved together" than really merged. The constituent programs had started out using different (but quite similar) libraries for similar purposes, and though they were working to merge things more cleanly, they still did. In a fair number of cases, the only way to guess what type would be returned by a given function was to know where that function had originated.

Even in such a case, you can help make quite a few things clearer. In that case, all the code started out in the global namespace. Simply moving a fair amount into some namespaces eliminated the name clashes and eased type-tracking quite a bit as well.

Comment: Disagree. A function can be named amazingly but still doesn't tell you which EXACT class is being used.

Comment: While it's true that function naming is important, relying entirely on the name reminds me a bit too much of relying on comments. A name can lie. A returned type can be (isn't always) enforced by the compiler. Also, if an API changes the return type of a function from `int` to `short` or something in v2.0, neither auto nor explicit type would warn me about it, but auto would make my own variables shorts (possibly causing UB) whereas explicit type would safely promote it to int. Neither option is great, I'm not sure how valuable `auto`'s "flexibility" is in this case.

Comment: Also I'm not particularly thrilled at the idea of baking even more information into the name of something; the function name has a lot going on already. The name already has to 1) provide a brief way to identify the function, 2) explain how the function differs from other functions, 3) indicate allocation (e.g., "create") to that auto adds 4) what the function returns in a high enough level way that it could apply to "varying types", 5) who owns what the function returns; I think you'd get names like `createAnyKindOfDataNode_SharedPointer()`

Comment: "Once you've fixed that real problem, readability of the code using auto will generally be just fine." It is funny when people assume that you have full ownership of the code you use, which is basically 1% of the cases or even less. Most SW engineer life consists of using 3rd party libraries... Good luck fixing that. And yes auto is an abomination for readability when you inherit a codebase to build on top. And saying this is not C++'s problem is just delusional and out of touch with reality

Comment: @Mehdi: Using terrible code, then blaming `auto` because it doesn't fix how terrible that code is strikes me as a bit strange. No, I'm not saying you should always use `auto`, but you also shouldn't blame it for problems caused by something else entirely.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it makes it easier to know the type of your variable if you don't use `auto`. The question is: do you *need* to know the type of your variable to read the code? Sometimes the answer will be yes, sometimes no. For example, when getting an iterator from a `std::vector<int>`, do you need to know that it's a `std::vector<int>::iterator` or would `auto iterator = ...;` suffice? Everything that anybody would want to do with an iterator is given by the fact it's an iterator - it just doesn't matter what the type is specifically.

Use `auto` in those situations when it doesn't make your code harder to read.

Comment: If you don't know the iterator type, how would you know whether there's a vector (where the element is accessed by *iter) or a map (were the element is iter->second)?

Answer (score 15):

Personally I use `auto` only when it's absolutely obvious for the programmer what it is.

Example 1

```
std::map <KeyClass, ValueClass> m;
// ...
auto I = m.find (something); // OK, find returns an iterator, everyone knows that
```

Example 2

```
MyClass myObj;
auto ret = myObj.FindRecord (something)// NOT OK, everyone needs to go and check what FindRecord returns
```

Comment: This is a clear example of bad naming hurting readability, not really auto. No one has the faintest idea what "DoSomethingWeird" does, so using auto or not won't make it any more readable. You will have to check the docs either way.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, that name was for the sake of example only. Is it better now?

Comment: Ok, it's somewhat better now. I still find the variable is poorly named, though, which still hurts. Were you to write `auto record = myObj.FindRecord(something)` it would be clear that the variable type was record. Or naming it `it` or similar would make it clear it returns an iterator. Note that, even if you did not use `auto`, properly naming the variable would mean you don't need to jump back to the declaration to look at the type *from anywhere in the function*. I removed my downvote because the example isn't a complete strawman now, but I still don't buy the argument here.

Comment: To add to @R.MartinhoFernandes: the question is, is it really important now WHAT a "record" exactly is? It is I think more important THAT it is a record, the actual underlying primitive type is another abstraction layer.. So one would without auto probably have: `MyClass::RecordTy record = myObj.FindRecord (something)`

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, it is important.

Comment: @paul23: What does using auto versus the type gain you, then, if your only objection is "I don't know how to use this". *Either* makes you look it up anyway.

Comment: @GManNickG it tells me the exact type of of unimportance.

Comment: @GManNickG well, now you might have to look up three or more things. 1) You have to find `myObj` and see what class it is (because it probably would have used `auto` too, repeat until you find an explicit type) 2) you have to look up FindRecord to see what it returns, 3) you have to look up the return type of FindRecord to know what to call on it. Most documentation for OOP APIs is organized by type.

Answer (score 11):

Many good answers so far, but to focus on the original question, I do think Herb goes too far in his advice to use `auto` liberally. Your example is one case where using `auto` obviously hurts readability. Some people insist it is a non-issue with modern IDEs where you can hover over a variable and see the type, but I disagree: even people that always use an IDE sometimes need to look at snippets of code in isolation (think of code reviews, for instance) and an IDE won't help.

Bottom line: use `auto` when it helps: i.e. iterators in for loops. Don't use it when it makes the reader struggle to find out the type.

Answer (score 10):

This question solicits opinion, which will vary from programmer to programmer, but I would say no.  In fact in many cases just the opposite, `auto` can help to make code easier to understand by allowing the programmer to focus on the *logic* rather than the minutiae.

This is especially true in the face of complex template types.  Here is a simplified & contrived example.  Which is easier to understand?

```
for( std::map<std::pair<Foo,Bar>, std::pair<Baz, Bot>, std::less<BazBot>>::const_iterator it = things_.begin(); it != things_.end(); ++it )
```

.. or...

```
for( auto it = things_.begin(); it != things_.end(); ++it )
```

Some would say the second is easier to understand, others may say the first.  Yet others might say that a gratuitous use of `auto` may contribute to a dumbing-down of the programmers that use it, but that's another story.

Comment: +1 Haha, everyone is presenting `std::map` examples, additionally with complex template arguments.

Comment: @Nawaz:  It's easy to come up with crazy-long template names using `map`s. :)

Comment: @Nawaz: but I wonder why then no one is coming with range based for loops as the better and more readable alternative...

Comment: @PlasmaHH, not all loops with iterators can be replace with range-based `for` e.g. if iterators are invalidated in the loop body and so need to be pre-incremented or not incremented at all.

Comment: @PlasmaHH:  In my case, MSVC10 doesn't do range-based for loops.  Since MSVC10 is my go-to C++11 testbed, I don't really have much experience with them.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: not all loops use map iterators that are somewhat unintuitive to read, e.g. a simple loop over vector indices, where using auto would not get you any more readability.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I disagree, `for (auto& item : items)` is often still an advantage over explicitly naming the element type

Comment: I believe in `typedef std::pair<Foo,Bar> Location; typedef std::pair<Baz,Bot> Item; typedef std::map<Location,Item> ItemMap;` for a nice start. Then this post is only about `for(auto i = things.begin()` vs `for(ItemMap::iterator i = things.begin()` which is a well known positive use case for `auto`. The OP is past this I think. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I'm quite surprised that no one pointed out yet that auto helps if there is no clear type. In this case, you either work around this problem by using a #define or a typedef in a template to finding the actual usable type (and this is sometimes not trivial), or you just use auto.

Suppose you got a function, that returns something with platform-specific type:

```
#ifdef PLATFROM1
__int256 getStuff();
#else //PLATFORM2
__int128 getStuff();
#endif
```

Witch usage would you prefer?

```
#ifdef PLATFORM1
__int256 stuff = getStuff();
#else
__int128 stuff = getStuff();
#endif
```

or just simply

```
auto stuff = getStuff();
```

Sure, you can write

```
#define StuffType (...)
```

as well somewhere, but does

```
StuffType stuff = getStuff();
```

actually tell anything more about x's type? It tells it is what is returned from there, but it is exactly what auto is. This is just redundant - 'stuff' is written 3 times here - this in my opinion makes it less readable than the 'auto' version.

Comment: The correct way to handle platform specific types is to *`typedef`* them.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica use a using statement, not typedef.

Comment: @user997112 The cppreference.com says: "There is no difference between a type alias declaration and typedef declaration." As such, I don't care whether you use `typedef` or `using` to declare your type alias as long as you provide a proper portable name to your platform specific type. Your styleguide may declare that either `using` or `typedef` should be used for a specific project, but the moment such a rule leaves that scope, it becomes nothing more or less than a religious rule. And I consider religious rules harmful in the context of programming.

Comment: So you think they added a new keyword with no benefit?

Comment: Might cause UB if a value that fits in PLATFORM1 doesn't fit in some other platform's int. I'd definitely rather see a `typedef` or `using`.

Answer (score 3):

Readability is subjective; you'll need to look at the situation and decide what's best.

As you pointed out, without auto, long declarations can produce a lot of clutter. But as you also pointed out, short declarations can remove type information which may be valuable.

On top of this, I'd also add this: be sure you're looking at readability and not writeability.  Code that's easy to write is generally not easy to read and vice versa.  For instance, if I were writing, I'd prefer auto.  If I were reading, maybe the longer declarations.

Then there's consistency; how important is that to you?  Would you want auto in some parts and explicit declarations in others, or one consistent method throughout?

Comment: "long declarations can produce a lot of clutter" one 'using' statement removes the clutter. No need for auto.

Answer (score 2):

I have two guidelines:

- If the type of the variable is obvious, tedious to write or hard to
  determine use auto.

  ```
  auto range = 10.0f; // Obvious

  for (auto i = collection.cbegin(); i != cbegin(); ++i) // Tedious if collection type
  // is really long

  template <typename T> ... T t; auto result = t.get(); // Hard to determine as get()
  // might return various stuff
  ```
- If you need specific conversion or the result type is not obvious and might cause confusion.

  ```
  class B : A {}; A* foo = new B(); // 'Convert'

  class Factory { public: int foo(); float bar(); }; int f = foo(); // Not obvious
  ```

Comment: What have you gained from using auto instead of float? 1 character? And then you've not even gained that because you added "f" at the end. So what was the point?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
It decreases verbosity but the common misunderstanding is that verbosity decreases readability. 
This is only true if you consider readability to be aesthetic rather than your actual ability to intepret code - which is not increased by using auto.
In the most commonly cited example, vector iterators, it may appear on the surface that using auto increases the readability of your code.
On the other hand, you don't always know what the auto keyword will give you. You have to follow the same logical path as the compiler does to make that internal reconstruction, and a lot of the time, particular with iterators, you're going to make the wrong assumptions.

At the end of the day 'auto' sacrifices readability of code and clarity, for syntactic and aesthetic 'cleanliness' (which is only necessary because iterators have needlessly convoluted syntax) and the ability to maybe type 10 fewer characters on any given line.
It's not worth the risk, or the effort involved long-term.

Answer (score 1):

I will take the point of less readable code as an advantage, and will encourage the programmer to use it more and more. Why? Clearly if the code using auto is difficult to read, then it will be difficult to write too. The programmer is  **forced to use the meaningful variable name** , to make his/her job better. 
Maybe in the beginning the programmer may not write the meaningful variable names. But eventually while fixing the bugs, or in code review, when he/she has to explain the code to others, or in not so near future, he/she explaining the code to maintenance people, the programmer will realize the  mistake and will use the meaningful variable name in future.

Comment: At best, you'd get people writing variable names like `myComplexDerivedType` to make up for the missing type, which clutters the code by the type repetition (everywhere the variable is used), and which entices people to omit the *purpose* of the variable in its name. My experience is, that there is nothing as unproductive as actively putting obstacles in the code.